# "cannot allocate memory in static TLS block" in a Python Flask application

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I've searched online but haven't found anything that fixed my issue. I'm writing a web app in Flask using Python, but after transferring my data to a new computer and recreating the virtual environment, I'm no longer able to use Flask's built-in development web server. I'm getting the traceback below. I can't tell if the issue lies in the SQL or Flask modules, but I've tried reinstalling and compiling them from source to no avail. The application throws the same error even when not in the virtual environment, as well.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2020 14:29:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1020, in __call__
    return self.registry[key]
KeyError: 139700690765568

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1969, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2268, in process_response
    self.session_interface.save_session(self, ctx.session, response)
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_session/sessions.py", line 534, in save_session
    saved_session = self.sql_session_model.query.filter_by(
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 519, in __get__
    return type.query_class(mapper, session=self.sa.session())
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 78, in __call__
    return self.registry()
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1022, in __call__
    return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3286, in __call__
    return self.class_(**local_kw)
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 138, in __init__
    bind = options.pop('bind', None) or db.engine
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 937, in engine
    return self.get_engine()
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 956, in get_engine
    return connector.get_engine()
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 561, in get_engine
    self._engine = rv = self._sa.create_engine(sa_url, options)
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 966, in create_engine
    return sqlalchemy.create_engine(sa_url, **engine_opts)
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 500, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 87, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 118, in dbapi
    return __import__("MySQLdb")
  File "/home/jhonig/ttx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might come across this issue, there was an issue with the `libmysqlclient21` package, which was fixed in the `8.0.21` version:

Bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/opencv/+bug/1890170

Fix: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-8.0/+bug/1889851

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading my system using `sudo apt upgrade` seemed to fix the issue, though I don't know how. It appears that some MySQL packages were updated though, so maybe it was a bug?

For posterity, here is a list of packages that were upgraded:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libmysqlclient-dev libmysqlclient21 libmysqlclient21:i386 linux-generic
  linux-headers-5.4.0-7634 linux-headers-5.4.0-7634-generic linux-headers-generic
  linux-image-5.4.0-7634-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev
  linux-modules-5.4.0-7634-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-7634-generic
  linux-system76 openjdk-8-jre-headless pop-shell
15 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```